# What is a good OOP way to handle events in classes that represent DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

So I'm in the midst of doing a big re-factor of a JavaScript-heavy personal project with the intention of better adhering to object-oriented design principles. I am experienced with OOP in more typically object-oriented languages (C#, C++, Java), but am fairly new to writing JavaScript that adheres to OO-design.

I'm wondering what is a clever way to structure objects that reflect DOM elements that interact with one another.

Here's my problem:

I have a single-page web app with three main elements: a search form, a graph, and a table. Previously these elements were handled by 'draw' methods called in order from the "submit" button event in the search form. The submit event would call a search method that returns data, and then call a `drawTable(data)` and `drawGraph(data)`, which draw the elements from the data returned.

I am trying to re-factor this to better adhere to OO principles. Rather than using a `drawTable()` function , I am creating a `table()` class which encapsulates a data structure, and a `.draw()` method that draws the element based on its member data.

All of this seems like a straightforward improvement in readability and design, and allows me to use a `Controller()` type class to instantiate and manipulate objects on the page. However what I'm struggling with is how to cleanly integrate the `Form()` into this design pattern. The form contains a submit button. Right now, since all the functions are in the same (global) scope, the `submit()` event can just call `drawTable()` and `drawGraph()` directly. However now, since `Form.submit()` cannot access the `Graph.draw()` method, I am unsure how to cleanly design this. Putting the submit event in a parent `Controller()` would solve this issue but seems to violate the encapsulation of the `Form()` that I am hoping to preserve.

Is there a good way of structuring these classes that preserves this functionality but still adheres to good object-oriented design?

Comment: You can try using the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: Pass a callback from the controller to the form.

Comment: This question, while interesting, seems like it will draw broad or subjective answers.